# Does passing an instance of a structure as a parameter to different threads make it global? C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, parameters, parameter-passing, structure

If I make an instance of a structure (which contains for example an int called 'count' and an array of another structure called 'date' (which has day and month etc.)), and I pass this instance as a parameter to each thread in an array of threads as I create them, and one might change a value of count, will the other threads be made aware of this change?

```
struct Struct_eg {
   int count;
   Date DOB; // just a filler e.g.
};

int numbers = 0;

Struct_eg instance;
instance.count = numbers;

for(int i = 0; i <= num_threads; i++) // (and I check for errors in creation in the real code)                                              
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread, (void *) &instance);

void *thread(void *parameter) {        
struct Struct_eg *param = (struct Struct_eg *) parameter;
param->count += 1;
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't use `std::thread`?

Comment: You need to add mutex lock or other form of thread synchronization. Otherwise changing the value of count will create a race condition. Note that synchronization is mandatory regardless of whether `instance` is global or not. And no, it is not possible to change variable scope (global / not global) after declaration.

Comment: Passing stuff to threads doesn't make it global. But better post valid code.

Comment: @ChristianHackl because I've been trying to learn about POSIX threads, they're covered in a textbook I've been reading (if that answers your question?).

Comment: @VTT and so if I insert appropriate semaphores/mutexes etc. - will that mean that the changes will be known across the different threads?

Comment: Yes. But that does not mean that `instance` becomes global all of it sudden.

Comment: @Carol: Well, most things that are hard about multi-threading are the same in every library and every programming language. It's just that with the advent of standard C++ multi-threading in C++11, there is much less reason to use POSIX threads directly.

Comment: Don’t learn pthreads, they are „obsolete“ in modern C++.

Comment: You try to share objects between threads, that‘s the problem. If they are global is irrelevant.

Comment: Your title and question doesn't match. Global refers to variables declared in the global scope.